# Найти максимальную длину цепочки "cvv" + "ccv" в строке

Tags: python-3.x, строки, условия, подстрока

Необходимо определить максимальную длину цепочки подстрок вида "согласная + любая буква + гласная", идущих подряд, в данной строке. Доступный алфавит - "AOCDF".
Хотелось узнать, почему необходимо сбрасывать счетчик к двум, а не к нулю? (counter = 2)

```py
s = open('24.txt').readline() #len(s) == 262144
max_ = 0
counter = 0
for i in range(0,len(s)-2,3):
    s = s.replace('D', 'c').replace('C','c').replace('A','v').replace('O','v').replace('F','c')
    if ((s[i]+s[i+1]+s[i+2]) in 'ccv') or ((s[i]+s[i+1]+s[i+2]) in 'cvv'):
        counter += 1
        max_ = max(max_,counter)
    else:
        counter = 2 #почему необходимо определять c = 2?
print(max_) # --> 6
```

[24.txt](https://easyupload.io/sucmk5)

Comment: что понимается под *длиной цепочки* ? длина  строки, состоящей из таких *шаблонов* ? а может количество этих *шаблонов* в строке, состоящей из них ? в любом случае код выдает неверный ответ. 
`s = 'DODDAADAA'` показывает `4`. если рассмотреть длину строки, то ответ должен быть `6`; если рассмотреть кол-во подряд идущих вхождений *шаблонов* - ответ `2`.

Comment: верный ответ = 6. 
Определите максимальное количество идущих подряд троек символов вида согласная + любая буква + гласная. Да, это странно, что для этой задачи ответ верный, а для других (с короткими строками) - неверный. Вот поэтому и спросил, почему counter = 2

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо пройти 3 последовательных цикла: 1 начинается с [0], 2 - [1], 3-[2], с шагом +3, с концом len(s)-2. Таким образом переберутся все возможные варианты, если бы цепочка начиналась: с первого / со второго / с третьего элемента. Четвертый элемент смысла рассматривать нет

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код совсем не рабочий. Для строки *DDDA* он возвращает *0*, а правильный ответ *3*. Для полного файла он вернёт неверный ответ. Надо только вынести шесть вызовов `replace` из цикла.

Но задача интересная. Пусть *s* - строка символов длиной *n*. Пусть *f<sub>i</sub>* - самая длинная "правильная" последовательность из троек, которая заканчивается в позиции *i*, *0 ≤ i < n*. Что про неё можно сказать?

- если *i < 2*, то *f<sub>i</sub> = 0*;
- если *i ≥ 2* и тройка *s<sub>i-2</sub>s<sub>i-1</sub>s<sub>i</sub>* неправильная, то *f<sub>i</sub> = 0*;
- если *i ≥ 2* и тройка *s<sub>i-2</sub>s<sub>i-1</sub>s<sub>i</sub>* правильная, то *f<sub>i</sub> = f<sub>i-3</sub> + 3*.

Последовательность *f* можно построить итеративно. Причём хранить нужно только три последних значения. То есть константная память. Код ниже так и делает - `f0`, `f1`, `f2` - три последних значения *f*, которые меняются местами по кругу. Итерация ведётся двумя итераторами для первого и третьего символа в тройке:

```
import sys


def longest(s):

    def gen():
        it = iter(s)
        next(it, None)
        next(it, None)

        f0, f1, f2 = 0, 0, 0
        for c1, c2 in zip(s, it):
            if c1 in 'CDF' and c2 in 'AO':
                f0, f1, f2 = f1, f2, f0 + 3
                yield f2
            else:
                f0, f1, f2 = f1, f2, 0


    return max(gen(), default=0)


print(longest(sys.stdin.read()))
```

Полсекунды и ответ готов:

> ```
> $ time python cvv-ccv.py < 24.txt 
> 18
>
> real  0m0.414s
> user  0m0.416s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```